# How to replace string from quote to quote?

Tags: php, replace

I have problem, can help me?
I have text and I want to replace it from " to ".

```
<span>new var[128]; format(var, sizeof(var), "something %s %f", "Stuneris", 1589.0587); SendClientMessage(playerid, 0xFFFFFFFF, var);</span>
```

And I want `"something %s %f"` and `"Stuneris"` replace to `<span class="numb">"something %s %f"</span>` and `<span class="numb">"Stuneris"</span>`

And other problem is to replace HEX codes from `0xFFFFFFFF` to `<span class="numb">0xFFFFFFFF</span>`.

What I need to do?

Comment: You need to use `str_replace`

Comment: I know that, njk, but how to do from quote to quote?

Comment: Are you looking for a literal solution (i.e. these two specific instances) or a generic solution that will replace all hex codes and all strings between quotes?

Comment: The literal solution for this specific case would be editing by hand, so I guess the OP is searching for a generic solution.

Comment: @Pharaoh - not necessarily... it may be that a specific string is sometimes returned from a function, or that this is the result of user-input data, where the elements other than the replacements in question are different. However, I'd also guess that he's looking for a general solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the HEX codes is easy:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(0x[0-9a-f]+)/i','<span class="numb">$1</span>',$text);
```

Replacing the strings within quotes is a bit more tricky. The main issue is to inlcude `"something %s %f"`, but exclude `", "` (which separates the quoted strings, but will also look like a quoted string). If you can be sure there will never be a comma in any of the strings, you'd use:

```
$text = preg_replace('/("[^",]+")/i','<span class="numb">$1</span>',$text);
```

If you must allow for a comma, this will exclude all strings that start with a comma:

```
$text = preg_replace('/("(?!,)[^"]+")/i','<span class="numb">$1</span>',$text);
```

Comment: adding the comma restriction is probably not necessary.. If a string is quoted before the comma it will first replace that one, which means that the double-quote won't be there messing up the second replacement. I would, however, suggest that you add ? to make the expression ungreedy

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace('/"([^"]*)"/', '<span class="numb">"\1"</span>', $string);
```

To match hex codes:

```
preg_replace('/0x([0-9A-Fa-f]*)/', '<span class="numb">\1</span>', $string);
```